# How to focus to an mesh object in react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

here in the app component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';

// canvas
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "react-three-fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Stars } from '@react-three/drei';
import Box from './Box';

const Box = ({ position, args, color }) => {
  const mesh = useRef(null);
  return (
    <mesh
      position={position}
      ref={mesh}
      onClick={() => {
        // zoom the camera to this object
      }}
    >
      <boxBufferGeometry attach='geometry' args={args} />
      <meshStandardMaterial attach='material' color={color} />
    </mesh>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas colorManagement>

        <Stars />
        <ambientLight intensity={1.6} />
        <Box position={[2, 0, 0]} args={[3, 3, 2]} color="green" />
        <Box position={[-2, 0, 0]} args={[1, 2, 1]} color="red" />

        <OrbitControls />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
}
```

Now, I want some functionality to change or zoom the camera to a mesh object when we click on it... Can we use any camera to achieve this? or any other plugins or libraries that I can use?

How can I do that?

i am using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^7.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-spring": "^9.2.4",
    "react-three-fiber": "^6.0.13",
    "sass": "^1.38.0",
    "three": "^0.131.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Comment: https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#controls
This documentation says you have to refer a camera to OrbitControls.. You also need to add a perspective camera if you haven't done so

Comment: I saw this on discourse https://discourse.threejs.org/t/lerping-camera-and-lookat-together-with-dynamic-taret-react-three-fiber/28896 might just be what you want. Focus and zoom will cost you some math. Btw the R3f package is wrong, it's supposed to be @react-three/fiber